# How to add up values in same row for multiple rows (Excel)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a issue with excel where we want to subtract Column A from B and display this in row C

The above is simple enough however we need to do this for each row for 8000 rows and it will take a long time to do the below for every row

=SUM(B1-A1)

We need a forumula which we can copy and paste for all 8000 rows

Something along the lines of

=SUM(B-A)

Comment: What do you mean it takes a long time? This is as basic as it gets pretty much. And you can just drag down the formula. This will autoadjust the row its refering to > `=SUM(B2-A2)` etc etc.. Otherwise, maybe update your question with a visual representation of your problem. *Sidenote:* You have about 23 questions asked but only one with an accepted answer. Please revisit your older threads and see if you can accept/upvote answers of people trying to solve your issues.

Answer (score 1):

### Navigate to a Far Away Cell (CTRL+G)

If you don't know how to get to row `8000` easily you just type into the `Name box` (probably the left-most text box above the spreadsheet) e.g. `C8000` and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. You could also learn how to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>:

- Navigate to cell `C1` and write the formula `=B1-A1`.
- Navigate back to cell `C1` and hold down <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and press <kbd>C</kbd> (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) to copy.
- Hold down <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and press <kbd>G</kbd> (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>). A window opens.
- Into the bottom text box input `C8000` and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> or click "OK".
- Hold down <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> and press <kbd>UP</kbd> / <kbd>↑</kbd> (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>UP</kbd>)`.
- Hold down <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and press <kbd>V</kbd> (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) to paste.

Instead of steps `3.` and `4.`, you can just write `C8000` into the previously mentioned `Name Box`.

If you meant to display the result in one cell then you can use one of these formulas:

```
=SUM(B:B)-SUM(A:A)
=SUMPRODUCT(B:B-A:A)
```

or you can specify the exact range like this:

```
=SUM(B1:B8000)-SUM(A1:A8000)
=SUMPRODUCT(B1:B8000-A1:A8000)
```

Answer (score 0):

## The Easy Way

Type the formula below into cell C1.

```
=SUM(B1-A1)
```

At the bottom right hand corner of cell C1, double click the green square (highlighted in the image provided).  This should duplicate your formula to the bottom of your dataset.

[image: Cell C1 image here]